# Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0) in JDBCTemplate while retrieving count from with queryForObject() method

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc, prepared-statement, jdbctemplate

I am trying to get count of rows with jdbctemplate.queryForObject(query,Object[]{},Integer.class) method , i have defined query in mysql.properties file and  passed a parameter to object[] but still getting exception, please help

> ```
>  mysql.properties :
> ```

```
    getCustomerRows=SELECT count(cm.`customer_master_id`) FROM customer_master cm WHERE cm.branch_code =?;
```

> ```
>   CustMasterDaoImpl :
> ```

```
    private @Value("${getCustomerRows") String getCustomerRows;
    @Override
    public Integer getCustomerRows(Integer branchCode) {
        try {


            return getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(getCustomerRows,new Object[] {branchCode},Integer.class) ;
        }catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("select Query failed : " + e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("catch ::: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

> Exception :

```
org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [${getKycComplinedCustomerRowsNonIndividual]; Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the bug, actually, I didn't set the value to `@Value` annotation properly for variable `getCustomerRows`, there is a missing closing curly brace in @Value annotation which gives (in this case) `java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range.` Exception